# conditional formatting based on two conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I'm struggling with Excel to properly write a condition formatting formula.

Here is an example of tab:
[Tab Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml4JJ.png)

Basically I would like to combine 2 conditions as describe below:

 **If Column B contains the text "Alpha" and Value in column C is below 5, then apply a specific format to the cell un column C.**

Does anybody know how to properly write this formula ?

I've tried =AND($B:$B="Alpha";$C:$C<5) but it doesn't work.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
=AND($B3="Alpha";$C3<5)
```

Firstly use that conditional formatting formula on cells C3, than 
apply this conditional format to =$C$3:$C$10 or any range you want.

To Apply this format to a range:
Conditional formatting >> Manage Rule >> Show formatting rules for: This worksheet >> Applies to: =$C$3:$C$10 >> OK

Answer (score -1):

Using your sample, I am using the following formula to format cells in column B

=AND($A$2="Alpha",$B$2<5)

Select cell B2 >> click on conditional formatting >> select new rule
on the window that opens up select

> > Use a formula to determine which cells to format
> >     Type =AND(
> >     click on cell A2
> >     type ="Alpha" and a comma (,)
> >     click on cell B2
> >     type <5)
> >     click format, and apply the format you need
> >     click OK
> >     click on conditional formatting
> >     chose manage rules
> >     in the field that reads Applies to
> >     make sure the you have the range where you want the conditional formatting

in your example it would be

=$B$2:$B$9

Hope this helps